# 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:IHostedService

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, background-task, asp.net-core-hosted-services, servicecollection

I am using .NET 5 and I want to run a background task using `IHostedService` classess as you can see:

```cs
public class PasargadJobs : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer = null!;
    readonly  ITerminalService _terminalService;
    readonly  IMessageService _messageService;
    readonly IMerchantService _merchantService;
    
    public PasargadJobs(
        IMerchantService merchantService,
        ITerminalService terminalService,
        IMessageService messageService)
    {
        _messageService = messageService;
        _terminalService = terminalService;
        _merchantService = merchantService;
    }
    
    //other parts of code are removed for short code
}
```

So I have to inject it to service collection as you can see :

```cs
services.AddHostedService<PasargadJobs>();
```

But after adding this I got this error :

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: MIMS.Portal.ScheduleJobs.PasargadJobs': Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MIMS.Portal.Infrustructure.Repositories.AppDbContext]' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)'

Here is my startup.cs

```cs
services.AddExpressiveAnnotations();

//--- DB Context ---//
services.AddTransient<AppDbContext, AppDbContext>();
//--- Repositories ---//
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
services.AddTransient<IMerchantRepository, MerchantRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IBankAccountRepository, BankAccountRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IBankRepository, BankRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IGeoRepository, GeoRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IInvoiceRepository, InvoiceRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IStoreRepository, StoreRepository>();
services.AddTransient<ITerminalRepository, TerminalRepository>();
services.AddTransient<ITicketRepository, TicketRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IFileRepository, FileRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IPartnerRepository, PartnerRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IStoreScopeRepository, StoreScopeRepository>();
services.AddTransient<ICommentRepository, CommentRepository>();
services.AddTransient<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IPosBrandRepository, PosBrandRepository>();
//-- Services --//
services.AddTransient<IMerchantService, MerchantService>();
services.AddTransient<IBankAccountService, BankAccountService>();
services.AddTransient<IBankService, BankService>();
services.AddTransient<IGeoService, GeoService>();
services.AddTransient<IDepartmentService, DepartmentService>();
services.AddTransient<IDeviceService, DeviceService>();
services.AddTransient<IInvoiceService, InvoiceService>();
services.AddTransient<IStoreService, StoreService>();
services.AddTransient<ITerminalService, TerminalService>();
services.AddTransient<ITicketService, TicketService>();
services.AddTransient<IUsersService, UsersService>();
services.AddTransient<IFilesManagerService, FilesManagerService>();
services.AddTransient<IMessageService, MessageService>();
services.AddTransient<IPartnerService, PartnerService>();
services.AddTransient<IStoreScopeService, StoreScopeService>();
services.AddTransient<INewsService, NewsService>();
services.AddTransient<ICommentService, CommentService>();
services.AddTransient<IPosBrandService, PosBrandService>();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(option =>
    {
        option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "localhost",
            ValidAudience = "localhost",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("wevhgfrtyhasdfghjklzxcvbnm"))
        };
    });
    
services.AddHostedService<PasargadJobs>();
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your hosted service is singleton and you have an indirect dependency to a scoped service:

`` Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MIMS.Portal.Infrustructure.Repositories.AppDbContext]' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService' ``

You can workaround the problem in the following ways

Inject [`IServiceScopeFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) into your hosted service and create the service scope manually like below

```cs
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedService>();
```

Do not put the `CreateScope` and `GetRequiredService` in the constructor of the hosted service: Since the hosted service is a singleton, the constructor will be called only once and hence instances created by `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()` will also be created once. So in this case you would use services that are designed to be short-lived as forever living singletons. Also do not forget to dispose `scope` after usage.

Since it looks like you are using Entity Framework Core and alternative to the approach above you could also consider to refactor your services to use [`IDbContextFactory<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)  so they can be registered as singelton services.

Comment: Thanks .I have changed the class :  readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        public PasargadJobs(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
  
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var _terminalService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITerminalService>();
            var _merchantService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMerchantService>();
            var _messageService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMessageService>();


        }

Comment: But the terminalService and merchandService and messageService asre null why ?

Comment: I can spot two issues: First: looks like you are assigning the services to local variables instead of fields: `var _terminalService = ...`  instead of `_terminalService = ...` like this you assign the service to a local variable and the field `_terminalService` remains `null`. Also do not create the services in the constructor, this will basically make all services singletons.

Comment: Thanks ,it worked .I moved them from constructor into my method and it works .

Comment: Do I really need to dispose the `scope`? You're using `using`, which will dispose that for me automagically at the end of the scope, anyway. Do I miss something?

Comment: `using` in the sample is enough. I just waned to highlight that is important to dispose scopes in some way.

Answer (score -1):

Implement a `BackgroundService` in your class. It already implements `IHostedService` and  `IDisposable`

```
public class PasargadJobs : BackgroundService

services.AddHostedService<PasargadJobs>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).